# Web Service in drupal 7

Tags: php, json, web-services, rest, drupal-7

I have a drupal 7 codebase in which a web service is written somewhere, which is being use by external iphone and android base applications, the url of web service in use by external applications is like.
http://example.com/api/module_name/find.json?param1=xxx&param2=xxx

I have to modify the above said web service to meet current requirements, but i am enabled to find the code file where web service is written.I have ftp access to the codebase.
The module being used is **services**, i need to know where can i found the file in which web service is defined in my drupal 7 file structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Open module_name.module
2. look for the `module_name_services_resources()` function
3. Identify the 'find' resource/action
4. Take note of the file it purports to be located in (current file if none provided).
5. Take note of the callback property, that's the name of the function used to process that resource.
6. Find that function either in the file from stage 4, or in the module file itself.
7. Go nuts.

It should be noted that if that isn't a custom module (i.e. it's a core/contrib one) then you shouldn't be manipulating the files directly.

Instead, implement `hook_services_resources_alter()` in your own module and point the applicable resources to files/callback functions under your control instead.

Comment: thanks for giving the direction i find the file and said function in step 2.